# Initializing third-part plugin in webpack bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

One of my module is external plugin (WOW effect), which needs to be initialize in index.html to works properly by using:

```
<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>
```

If I use the plugin as a completely external file - it works. But when I compile it with webpack it gives me an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: wow is not defined.

My config file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './modules/_entry.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

and _entry.js contains:

```
require("./wow.js");
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

---

1. **Externals** The benefit of this one is that you can easly exchange your local script file for example for a CDN one. *In this method, the source of the script is an external vendor file.*

   - Have a folder with you vendor scripts, like WOW.
   - Link to it in your HTML file using `<script src="vendors/WOW.js">`.
   - You are free to make the initialization like you indicated above, inside another `<script>` tag.
   - Add *externals* configuration to your webpack config:

```js
var config = {
  entry: [...],
  output: {...},
  externals: {
    Wow: 'WOW'
  },
  module: {...},
  plugins: [...]
};
```

- From now on, you have access to an *artificial* module `Wow` in all your application modules and you can `import` or `require` them (although in case of WOW, I don't think you would need it).

---

2. **Expose-loader** This way lets you move to the global scope modules that you would normally use as... well, modules :) *In this method, the source of the script is a module (either yours own, or installed with npm).*

   - Install the plugin: `npm install expose-loader --save-dev`
   - Add the expose loader configuration to your webpack config file:

```js
var config = {
  entry: [...],
  output: {...},
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      ...
    }, {
      test: 'path/to/your/module/wow.min.js',
      loader: "expose?WOW"
    }]
  },
  plugins: [...]
};
```

- This should make the `WOW` a global variable, usable inside `<script>` tags.

Comment: variable WOW is still undefined