# Wow.js with webpack and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I try to implement wow.js using react and webpack.

I install it via npm.

`npm install --save wow.js`

It install perfectly. Now the problem is how to import it properly. I can't make it work keep getting undefined.

I've tried few way:

First:

```
import wow from 'wow.js';
```

But webpack can't compile it. It says the module cannot be found. Even I using complete url `import wow from /node_modules/wow.js`

---

Second:

I'm using this solution from [here](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/233):

```
require('imports?this=>window!js/wow.js');
```

But I still get cannot find modules (i change the path to my node_modules).

---

Third:

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388104/initializing-third-part-plugin-in-webpack-bundle-js):

I'm using the expose module and try to `new WOW().init();` it says `Wow is undefined`.

I'm not using his first solution because I want my html to look simple only has `bundle.js` script.

---

I can't found any other solution. What should I do to make it work?.

Thanks!

---

my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'bootstrap-loader',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/js/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/build",
        publicPath: "/build/",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'react-hot!babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css!postcss'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!postcss!sass'
            },
            { test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000' },
            {
              test: 'path/to/your/module/wow.min.js',
              loader: "expose?WOW"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './'
    },
    postcss: [autoprefixer]
};
```

Comment: I think you're installing wow.js when its just wowjs acc to their github page.
https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the following steps

1. Install [`exports-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exports-loader)

   `npm i exports-loader --save-dev`
2. Add to `webpack.config.js` this loader

   ```
   {
      test: require.resolve('wow.js/dist/wow.js'), 
      loader: 'exports?this.WOW'
   }
   ```
3. add `import` to your app

   `import WOW from 'wow.js/dist/wow.js';`

Comment: could you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255074/wowjs-gatsby-referenceerror-wow-is-not-defined ?

Comment: wowjs 1.1.3^ goes like `test: require.resolve('wowjs/dist/wow.js'),`, no dot in wowjs import

Answer (score 14):

Alternative option without updating your wepack config.

1. Install WOW.js: `npm install wowjs`
2. Import in your component: `import WOW from 'wowjs';`
3. Under `componentDidMount()` of your component: `new WOW.WOW().init();`

   ```
   import React, {Component} from 'react';
   import WOW from 'wowjs';

   class Cmp extends Component {
     componentDidMount() {
       new WOW.WOW().init();
     }

     render() {
       /* code */
     }
   }

   export default Cmp;
   ```

Comment: This didn't work either. I used `new WOW.WOW().init()` but it still doesn't work. I can see in the rendered html that the animated class is indeed being added, but the animation doesn't run.

Comment: This worked great for me! Followed your instructions and voila!

Comment: What about these errors: `MutationObserver is not supported by your browser.` & `WOW.js cannot detect dom mutations, please call .sync() after loading new content.` Does anybody knows how to get rid of them?

Comment: import {WOW} from 'wowjs';
not working in version 1.1.3 
had some weird error about  weakmaps

Answer (score 0):

You can also change `.call(this)` to `.call(window)` (wow.js last line). Found this solution here https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/46574-how-to-add-js-library-from-bower