# react, jquery, gatsby - how to make jquery plugins work in gatsby?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, gatsby, wow.js

**Removed previous description as it's not relevant now.**

I started with fresh gatsby site and able to make jquery, bootstrap, wow and owl carousel work.

`layout.js`

```
import './expose'
import './main'
```

`expose.js`

```
import 'popper.js'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'animate.css/animate.min.css'
import WOW from 'wowjs/dist/wow.js';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel';

new WOW(
    {
        offset: 100,
        mobile: true,
      }
).init();
```

`main.js`

```
;(function($){
    console.log('hello jquery')
    console.log($(window).width())

    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Navbar 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    //* Navbar Fixed  
    function navbarFixed(){
        if ( $('.header_area').length ){ 
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();   
                if (scroll){
                    $(".header_area").addClass("navbar_fixed");
                } else {
                    $(".header_area").removeClass("navbar_fixed");
                }
            });
        };
    };
    navbarFixed();

    var $animation_elements = $('.scroll_animation');
    var $window = $(window);

    function check_if_in_view() {
        console.log('check_if_in_view')
      var window_height = $window.height();
      var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
      var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

      $.each($animation_elements, function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
        var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
        var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

        //check to see if this current container is within viewport
        if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
          (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
          $element.addClass('in-view');
        } else {
          $element.removeClass('in-view');
        }
      });
    }


    if($(window).width() > 576){
        $window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
        $window.trigger('scroll');
    }

    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();

})(window.jQuery)
```

**`jquery` sometimes work sometimes not.**

**Now, the issue is wowjs animation executes only once. Not able to run it again even If I refresh the page. owl carousel has the same issue. It appears once and then never appears back not even on page refresh. How do I make `jquery` code in `main.js` work all the time ? As the actual file has 1000 lines of jquery and jquery plugin code.**

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `WOW` in `layout.js` and trying to use it in `main.js`. This won't work.

There are two possible solution to this:

1) Add `import WOW from "wowjs"` to `main.js` so that it's available in the scope of `main.js`(works only if `main.js` is being bundled by webpack). Also for me `WOW` is available in `WOW.WOW` variable(console and check accordingly).

2) Attach `WOW` to window by yourself in `layout.js` and use it anywhere. This is probably bad.

**Update:**

Attach `WOW` to window by yourself before importing `main.js` and use it anywhere.

Solution here(Check `expose-wow.js` and `index.js` imports)

[image: Edit gatsby-starter-default]

Comment: I tried to bundle `main.js` with `expose-loader` in webpack but it didn't work.

Comment: do I need to do the same for jquery, jquery.carousel, isotop etc.. ?

Comment: I don't think so. AFAIK jquery attaches by itself to `window`. If you see `ReferenceError: ... is not defined` outside, you can try using the same logic. Let me know if it works.

Comment: yes error for wowjs is gone. Now getting an error for `owl.carousel` - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined`. I already have `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
            }),`

Comment: can you show me how to use jquery, bootstrap, wow, owl.carousel, isotope in your solution ?

Comment: I am not sure of your project structure. But you can install npm modules for each of the libraries and import them inside file similar to `expose-wow.js` and expose it to `window`. see if it works.